# How to keep running vagrant machine after restart

Tags: vagrant

I have created a vagrant machine which is using the LAMP. So, every time I restart the computer I have to use `vagrant up` to run VM. Is this possible to keep running vagrant machine so when I restart the computer it should remain running in the background? As to keep running Docker container we use `-d` to detach it with the process. Is this possible in `Vagrant`?

Comment: What about creating a statup script that `cd` into the directory and do `vagrant up` ?

Comment: how I can create this script? any help. thanks

Comment: Help with the shell script itself ? Or with how to add it to startup script ?

Comment: How to add it to the startup script. thanks

Comment: (I can't edit the comment but I meant startup script**s**) Adding a startup script depend on you distribution init system, you shoould search in you distribution documentation which init system(SysVInit, Systemd, Upstart etc...) it uses and then check how to add startup script to that init system.

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks for help.